# Как выбрать данные из курсора sys_refcursor возвращаемого из функции?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть функция, которая возвращает курсор с типом `sys_refcursor`.
Нужно обработать данные этого возвращаемого значения курсора в другой функции.

Как выбрать данные из этого курсора?

Comment: Приложите к вопросу код функции.

Comment: http://www.foxbase.ru/oracle-programming/ispolzovanie-ref-cursor.htm

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот простой рабочий пример, как выбрать данные из курсора в общем случае:

```sql
set serverout on
declare
    function getrefcur (n int) return sys_refcursor is
        rc sys_refcursor; 
    begin
        open rc for
            select 'row '||rownum from dual connect by level<=n; 
        return rc;
    end;
    function processrefcur (rc sys_refcursor) return varchar2 is
        val varchar2 (8);
        ret varchar2 (4000);
    begin
        loop fetch rc into val;
            exit when rc%notfound;
            ret := ret||val||';';
        end loop;
        ret := rtrim (ret, ';')||' #processed '||rc%rowcount||' rows'; 
        close rc;
        return ret;
    end;
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line (processrefcur (getrefcur (3)));    
end;
/
```

> row 1;row 2;row 3 #processed 3 rows